Upload large file to Share Point using Graph API and Java
I am not able to use this code to upload large files to share point as mentioned in the documentation.
This returns an error as below:
com.microsoft.kiota.ApiException: generalException
at com.microsoft.kiota.ApiExceptionBuilder.withMessage(ApiExceptionBuilder.java:45)
at com.microsoft.graph.core.requests.upload.UploadResponseHandler.handleResponse(UploadResponseHandler.java:62)
at com.microsoft.graph.core.requests.upload.UploadSliceRequestBuilder.put(UploadSliceRequestBuilder.java:69)
at com.microsoft.graph.core.tasks.LargeFileUploadTask.uploadSlice(LargeFileUploadTask.java:207)
at com.microsoft.graph.core.tasks.LargeFileUploadTask.upload(LargeFileUploadTask.java:131)

I am using the same code as mentioned in the documentation and the only change is the path of the file in share point. The variable destinationWithDate is some folder structure I need e.g. 2024/July/FolderA/FolderB/file.txt
UploadSession uploadSession = graphServiceClient.drives()
            .byDriveId(drive.getId())
            .items()
            .byDriveItemId("root:/"+destinationWithDate+":")
            .createUploadSession()
            .post(uploadSessionRequest);

The code fails at upload and the error returned does not tell much about it.
UploadResult<DriveItem> uploadResult = largeFileUploadTask.upload(maxAttempts, callback);

For the smaller files, this code works perfectly for me so I am assuming the destinationWithDate variable is not an issue:
graphServiceClient.drives().byDriveId(drive.getId()).items().byDriveItemId("root:/" + destinationWithDate + ":").content().put(fileStream);

I am using version 6.4.0 of Graph API. I tried a couple of older versions too but it did not help. Please help me with the larger file upload error. I could not find anything helpful so far related to larger file uploads using Graph API and Java.

public class LargeFileUploadSample {
    private static final int CHUNK_SIZE = 5 * 1024 * 1024; 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String driveId = "<YOUR_DRIVE_ID>";
        String filePath = "<YOUR_FILE_PATH>";
        String destinationPath = "root:/" + destinationWithDate + ":";
        GraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider(authProvider).buildClient();

        try {
            // Create upload session
            UploadSession uploadSession = graphClient.drives(driveId).items(destinationPath).createUploadSession(new DriveItemUploadableProperties()).buildRequest().post();

            // Upload file
            LargeFileUploadTask < DriveItem > uploadTask = new LargeFileUploadTask < > (uploadSession, graphClient, new File(filePath), CHUNK_SIZE, DriveItem.class);
            LargeFileUploadResult < DriveItem > uploadResult = uploadTask.upload();

            if (uploadResult.responseBody != null) {
                System.out.println("File uploaded successfully: " + uploadResult.responseBody.name);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Upload failed.");
            }
        } catch (ClientException e) {
            System.err.println("Error uploading file: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I get this exception:
com.microsoft.kiota.ApiException: generalException
at com.microsoft.kiota.ApiExceptionBuilder.withMessage(ApiExceptionBuilder.java:45)
at com.microsoft.graph.core.requests.upload.UploadResponseHandler.handleResponse(UploadResponseHandler.java:62)
at com.microsoft.graph.core.requests.upload.UploadSliceRequestBuilder.put(UploadSliceRequestBuilder.java:69)
at com.microsoft.graph.core.tasks.LargeFileUploadTask.uploadSlice(LargeFileUploadTask.java:207)
at com.microsoft.graph.core.tasks.LargeFileUploadTask.upload(LargeFileUploadTask.java:131)
